# Switch my middle letters, read me backwards I'm food. What am I?

Tags: riddle, anagram

> With only one I'm not possible
>
> Switch my middle letters, read me backwards I'm food
>
> Rearranged I'm many things,
>
> I'm part of this community,
>
> I can be a significant other
>
> and I won't bite

What am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you

> team

With only one I'm not possible

> team has more than one player

Read backwards I'm food

> meat

Rearranged I'm many things,

> anagrams of team are mate, tame, etc.

I'm part of this community,

> members of the team have specific characteristics

I can be a significant other

> a mate as in good friend

and I won't bite

> because I am tame

Comment: *"How do you know if someone is vegetarian?"*,  *"Don't worry, they'll tell you"*.

Comment: A mate as in "significant other" is unlikely to be just "a good friend". This phrase means spouse or partner. Fortunately still fits

Comment: Team read backwards gives maet, not really meat...

Comment: I'm part of this community probably refers to "meta".

Comment: @IAmInPLS crap can't believe I did that what a horrible mistake, I'll change it real fast.

Comment: @Jason_ i did too.(blunder of pz.se)

Comment: @numberknot, well great job you totally answered it correct.

Comment: @Jason_ one of the stack exchange community question,in which both question and answer are wrong...but still answer accepted.

Comment: numberknot I did mean to make the community question meta, scince that makes up alot of the communities on SE.  As stated by @vvye